# Obtener dato de una tabla mediante JQuery o Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en el cual requiero obtener un dato (ID) de una fila el cual su columna esta con el atributo `hidden`.

**Código de la tabla**

```
<table id="tbl_Datos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th hidden>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">1</td>
            <td>Juan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">2</td>
            <td>Paco</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">3</td>
            <td>Pedro</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que deseo es solo obtener un dato al seleccionar el checkbox y deseleccione si antes habia marcado algun otro checkbox. (Deseo obtener el id).

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta agregar el código que has intentado? ¿Por que usar `checkbox` y no `radio`?

Comment: @Marcos, no habia pensado en usar radio, realmente aun no implemento un codigo, he estado revisando en la red y no entiendo del todo los códigos, hay unos que utilizan la clase `each` de `JQuery` por eso recurrí SOes, en busca de una forma y el porque se debe de hacer asi. Lo del radio es un buen aporte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes cargar tus datos recorriendo el cuerpo de tu tabla, independientemente de las propiedades que tenga asigandas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        $("#tbl_Datos").find("tr").each(function (idx, row) {
          if (idx > 0) {
              var cbkbox = $("td:eq(2) input:checked", row).val();
              if(cbkbox) {
                  var JsonData = {};
                  JsonData.Id = $("td:eq(0)", row).text();
                  JsonData.Nombre = $("td:eq(1)", row).text();
                  JsonData.Seleccionar = cbkbox;
                  alert("Selecionaste a id: " + JsonData.Id + " Nombre:"  + JsonData.Nombre);
              }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_Datos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th hidden></th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">1</td>
            <td>Juan</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">2</td>
            <td>Paco</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td hidden="">3</td>
            <td>Pedro</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="datos"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Correr un each en la tabla te permitirá seleccionar cada celda, inclusive puedes llegar a ser muy especifico a los elemento que quieres leer, como con tu checkbox por ejemplo. 
[Recorriendo un tabla con jQuery [.each]](https://julitogtu.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/recorriendo-un-tabla-con-jquery-each/)

Comment: Hasta el punto de recorrer toda la tabla lo entiendo, pero como puedo obtener el valor de la fila a la cual estoy seleccionando, eso es lo que aun no me queda muy claro.

Comment: Entonces hay que aplicar ingenio sobre estas mismas herramientas, eh editado considerando los otros comentarios.

Comment: Perdon, no habia visto la edicion. Voy a probar y combinarlo con lo que ya tengo.

Answer (score 0):

Para encontrar el valor debes meter la tabla en un bucle, para este caso un "each".

Pero antes debes declarar las variables para guardar tu valor "hidden" y para el resto de la tabla

```
let _id= ''; // para guardar valor hidden
let _id2= ''; // para guardar otros valores
let _idX= ''; // para guardar otros valores

$("#tbl_Datos tr ").each(function (index, elemento) {

  _id  = $(elemento).find('td').eq(0).text() // para encontrar el valor hidden
  _id2 = $(elemento).find('td').eq(1).text() // para encontrar segundo valor
..........
  _idX = $(elemento).find('td').eq(x).text()  // x= ultimo valor de la tabla

});
```